# Difference between "right:0px;" to "float:right;" to "margin:auto;"?

Tags: css

I learn css and i get confused between those three things.
They are all doing the same thing - moving the block to the right screen position.

Is there any spicial thing in each one?

Answer (score 1):

They're *not* doing the same thing, they're *showing* the same thing, based on the code.

- `right: 0px`;

Aligns the item on which the property is specified to the right by forcing the distance between the right and the item to zero pixels, effectively setting it 'right' (requires absolute positioning though).

- `float: right`;

Let's the specified item 'float' to the right, but it is not being *forced* right. If another element is already there with the same float property, it will not overwrite that position (where solution 1 stacks).

This property listens to the parent element though, if the container of this element isn't touching the right side of document, it will not reach the right side.

See the DOM as the sea, and your element as a ship. It 'floats' with the wind (left/right) 'over' the DOM / water.

- `margin: auto`;

Doesn't even align anything to the right. Margin auto is a trick to **align stuff to the center** by forcing the *margin* between the elements to be exactly the same (automatically).